# How can the expected value of an estimator in least square equation be equal to real parameter?

Tags: least-squares, expected-value

Since the estimated parameter is constant then it's expected value will also be constant which would mean by proving 
E(b1) = B1 
we are proving that b1 = B1 
because E(b1) = b1.

Answer (score 1):

The expectation of your regression parameter is taken with respect to the noise. That is, you can draw many samples from the underlying population (as described by your noise term) and for each sample estimate the parameter. Thus, the parameter is not constant any more, but a random variable, so it makes sense to investigate its expectation. It turns out that [under certain conditions, this expectation exists and is equal to the true parameter value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Markov_theorem).